# scrape google codeSEARCH

Tags: web-scraping, web-crawler

Q: Advice on programming tools/scripts to automate the extraction of all project files from a Google code search result? 
NOTE: The question is specifically for code search: 
 http://www.google.com/codesearch
and NOT "google code" which already has repositary access.

Motivation: An open source project official site has long gone without any contact leads to chase up to revive it. The project files are still available but only in google codesearch results (for the moment). Unfortunatly there are too many files do feasible cut and pase them by one by one by hand.

All ideas welcome, thanks!

Edit: Closest reference found so far:
groups.google.com/group/google-code-search/browse_thread/thread/f643b42934ea75c9/974f99c5cd907e8e#974f99c5cd907e8e

Answer (score 1):

It sounds you need to utilize [wget](http://www.gnu.org/s/wget/) for this.